# PHP relative paths using home web server throwing errors

Tags: php, html, url, xampp, relative-path

I'm using XAMPP on my home machine and also using it as a web server.

I have a main folder which is for my site, I then have a dev folder where I'm trying to work on a new site. (not sure if this is relevant info but worth mentioning)

On my local machine the site is c:/MySite/Dev
within Dev I have something along the lines of

Dev
   assets
       css
       js
   includes
       footer
       header
   core
      init
   folder
      subfolder
           files.php
   index.php

init is included at the top of every page, header and footer includes are also included.  Within header is my nav bar.

I'm trying to define a site root so that I don't have to keep changing ../ and ../../ etc depending on the location of the files.

Also, seeing as my header gan be in many subfolders, the links to main index etc can get messy  as index.php from a subfolder won't take me to the root index.php

I've tried using **DIR** and SERVER_ROOT bt of which I couldn't get to work properly, server root returned the c:/www and **DIR** returned the folder of the file in which it was called.

I'm still new to php so learning as I go.

This is what I've tried:

in init:

```
define("WEB", "http://mySite.com/Dev");
$environment = WEB;

echo $environment;
```

this works in the first instance, then when I'm in the subfolder and try using the home link I get :

```
http://mySite.com/Dev/Folder/Subfolder/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Undefined%20variable:%20environment%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:/www/Dev/includes/header.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E38%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E/index.php
```

can anyone help please?

EDIT: The error after cleaning the output:

```
http://mySite.com/Dev/folder/subfolder/
Notice: Undefined variable: environment in C:/www/dev/includes/header.php on line 38
/index.php
```

Comment: Use URL Decoding to remove all the junk you are getting there to get a better clue of whats happening. I see some 'undefined' output which means something is being injected into the URL that doesn't exist
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: surely I shouldn't have to do that though?!  THis is jsut a link in a nav bar : <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $environment;?>/index.php">Home</a></li>

Comment: line 38 is where I have the link <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $environment;?>/index.php">Home</a></li>

I've not included the init in the header as it's already included in the file that inscludes it in the first place.  Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: But are you trying to use the `$environment` variable you defined in one PHP file, in another PHP file?